# Get a page redirect with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have an iFrame which has several links on the page which is inside the iFrame.

From the outside document, how can I tell if the page in the iFrame has been redirected?

```
<body>
    <script>
        if(somePage.html has been redirected) {
            //do something
        }
    </script>

    <iframe src="somePage.html">...</iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: And it's all happening on the same domain, no cross domain sites in the iFrame

Comment: @adeneo the new page will come from a new domain, but `somePage.html` is on my domain.

Comment: Then I don't think you can, the source wouldn't change when a link inside the iframe changes, so I would assume one had to access the iFrame and get the location, but iframes with cross domain content can't be accessed. Maybe someone has a clever method to do it ?

Comment: @adeneo so you are right, I get a security error when I try to get the body element of the new page. But for my case, all I need to do is get the height of the new page so I can adjust the iFrame height. Trying to avoid scrollbars for cleanliness

Comment: @adeneo would there be anyway to get the height of the page inside the iframe regardless of the domain origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the iframe an **id** and try putting an `load()` function in the `document.ready()` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("iframeID").load(function () {
        //iframe loaded
        alert(this.contentWindow.location);
    });
});
```

Comment: it works... but I get a security error when I try to get elements from that page.

Comment: 1: `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

2: `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "https://docs.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "file", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.`

Comment: I completely understand the errors, and is out of the scope of this question. But I do not believe what I want to do can be done.

Comment: I see. Well, I think what @adeneo mentioned in his comment above is legit. Cross domain content cannot be accessed, and this solution is dependent asumed on 'knowing' current page.

Comment: well your solution actually works 100%. If a new page is loaded I can catch that load. So I think to solve my height issue what I will end up doing is just adding a scrollbar to the iFrame if a new page is loaded

Comment: Cool. For that, just add an `overflow` to your iframe styling as per suggested in your `window.onload` handler.. but I presume you knew that already. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks! shouldn't be too difficult ;)